# MediaPlayer plugin does not work

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying play Audio by html5 audio tag in Cordova App.  On iOS 9.0 and browser everything works fine but on Android it doesn't play.

My source Code:

```
<audio width="300" autoplay height="32" src="http://static.weareswoop.com/audio/charlestown/track_1.mp3" ></audio>
```

I get output

> error (1, -1004)

Next way I'm trying to use Cordova Media Plugin. Result was the same. On iOS everything works fine but on Android does not work.

My source code:

```
scope.playAudio = function(url) {
// Play the audio file at url
var my_media = new Media(url,
    // success callback
    function () {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function (err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
    }
);
// Play audio
my_media.play();
```

}

My Android Version is 4.4. Cordova 6.0. Someone have any idea how resolve this problem ? I can't find any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ruled out that it's not just due to the Browser you're using on Android? Tried firefox, chrome and opera and they all returned the same error?

Comment: This is not Browser problem. I was trying on browsers in my computer and everything was ok. In my Android App was error output.

Answer (score 0):

what about using Audio instead of Media?

```
var audio = new Audio('./sounds/beep_ok.mp3').play();
```

Comment: I did it from this web: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/06/23/Cordova-Media-API-Example/ and everything works fine.